# Как получить элементы массива?

Tags: массивы, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить значение элемента массива [date]

Массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2014-02-25 00:00:00
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Etc/GMT-4
        )

    [1] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2014-03-04 00:00:00
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Etc/GMT-4
        )

    [2] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2014-03-11 00:00:00
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Etc/GMT-4
        )

    [3] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2014-03-19 00:00:00
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Etc/GMT-4
        )

)
```

Я пробовал вот так (выводит какие-то *2E*):

```
foreach ($myArray as $level1)
{
    foreach ($level1 as $level2)
    {
        echo $level2['date'];
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Нужно получить элемент массива

Comment: т.к. $level1 у тебя является объектом, а не массивом ([0] => DateTime Object), к нему нельзя обращаться, как к массиву.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Красивее (да и правильнее будет так):

```
foreach($arr as $dt)
    echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```